# recognize function from bitmap graphic?

Tags: math, ocr

This is really the very first try.. so all kind of suggestions are welcome. I am looking for software that recognizes a mathematical function from a bitmap / jpg. E.g. if you have the graph of some log(x) as jpg and you´d enter the x,y scales the program should tell that log(x) was used to create this. Maybe some OMR software might help, maybe it´s rather some math tool. 
Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bitmap - convert it to a 2 column data (for example "x y" of black pixels and ignore the white) set so that software can easily analyze it.

If you know the possible choice of functions that it could be (log, sin, exp) then you can use a simple minimization routine like Levenberg-Marquadt to fit a function and look at the fitness score (whichever one has lowest wins!)

If you have no idea what the function is - http://www.zunzun.com/

Good luck!

Comment: sounds like a plan. Do you have any suggestions how to do the conversion from bitmap to x,y ?

Comment: :( Not really. Normally a picture that contains graph information was created from the x,y data -- Seek the source!

Answer (score 0):

hi
you must creat a neural net(mlp or hopfield) then with a set of matrices:p for entry and t for target learning your net. after you sure of the performance of your net, you can use from yor net to recognize all picture(bitmap) that convert to a matrix. all of this possible in matlab, however you most first learn neural net.